# Posting two forms simultaneously using Ajax/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, paypal

I have a form that posts to post.php, and a form that posts to Paypal. I want it so that when I click on the Paypal submit button, it posts both forms and goes to the page where the Paypal button would take you.

However, I ran into a wall with this and I'm not sure what the cause is. The form goes to the Paypal page fine, but doesn't POST my other, non-paypal form.

Here's my JS: http://slexy.org/view/s2u2Jsr2RI

Here's my HTML: http://slexy.org/view/s2gc4q8CHe

Here's my post.php: http://slexy.org/view/s208WfbKso

Here are the lines of jQuery which I believe to be the root of the issue:

```
$('#paypalButton').click(function(){
     $.post('post.php', $('#myForm').serialize(), function(){
               $('#paypal').submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: The serialize method of jQuery maybe doesn't works because your form ("myForm") is not semantically correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paypal form is being submitted first because you have the input field as a `type="image"`. That acts as a submit button

Comment: Just want to add: You can either override the submit handler of that paypal form in jQuery to then do your first post (then submit the paypal form), or change the input field to a button to handle the click (and youll have to handle the image display differently)

Answer (score 0):

This works: just prevent the event's default action of posting the form.

```
$(function(){
    $('#paypalButton').click(function(**event**){
        **event.preventDefault();** 
         $.post('post.php', $('#myForm').serialize(), function(){
               $('#paypal').submit();
         });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi CheezWeezil, welcome to StackOverflow.  You can indent code (or other quotable content) using 4 spaces on each line, or the { } in the WYSWYG editor.  Keeps things readable.